# checkbox checked only if data in backend is true

Tags: sql, asp.net, razor

I would like my checkbox to be checked in frontend (*.cshtml) only if it is true in backend i.e. in the SQL Server. I searched a lot for similar questions but they were not relevant for cshtml. (So please don't mark my question duplicate.)

An example: I have records of Employee. There are columns EmployeeId, EmployeeName and IsPresent in the table. The frontend should show the Employees records and their respective checkboxes. In the checkbox it will show checked if he/she is actually present. (the user comes and checks in through thumb punching and IsPresent goes high/true.)

But from the frontend (developed in cshtml and jquery), the HR guy should become able to uncheck or check the record and that change will reflect on the Server after clicking.

Here is my input tag:

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked 
        onclick="postEmp(@emp.EmpId, @emp.IsPresent)">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

(FYI: I need to put this thing inside an Array.) Now, my question is how do I gain little more control over that keyword `checked`? I don't want it to be checked when IsPresent is false on the database.

Here is my POST code although it is less relevant right now:

```
function postEmp(empId, val) {        
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/Test/PutDynamicEmp',
            data: { EmpId: empId, IsPresent: val },
            success: console.log(" successful!"),
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: So where exactly are you facing the issue in implementing this. Are you not getting the checkbox checked when originally loading the page??

Comment: @GaganDeep No. I should explicitly write it `checked` to make/keep it checked. And that would check all other employees' IsPresent which is unwanted. I want it to be checked if IsPresent is true in the backend database.